# Python select epoll in Gevent

Tags: python, gevent, epoll

I'm working on GPIO stuff in Python, need to register the fd on epoll, since gevent monkey patched the python select library, there will not be select.epoll if monkey.patch_all(select=True), so here comes two questions:

1. Will be consequence that the monkey.patch_all(select=False)?
2. Or does Gevent provide its own epoll register stuff?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gevent does not provide their own epoll implementation yet.
If you don't monkeypatch select it will block the entire process instead of just one greenlet.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've found that adafruit GPIO python library. In its c code , a new thread is created for such purpose, just need to check its common.c file for the GPIO mapping, I've no problem since. Thank you again for the select block info. Nice weekend